# Homeomorphism in Algebraic Topology

Tags: general-topology

I am studying the Algebraic Topology course (Homeomorphism Topic). While solving the Exercise, I stuck in a question, in which I have been asked to find the Homeomorphism between 2 subspaces X and Y of $\Bbb R^2$, where $X=\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 ; x \ge y \ge 0\}$ and $Y=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 ; x \in [0,+ \infty) , y \in [0, \pi /2] \}$....

Please guide...

Comment: Have you tried drawing them ? Also, can you see why $Y$ is homeomorphic to the same thing with $\pi/4$ instead of $\pi/2$ ? that might help for explicit mappings

Comment: This appears to be more of a "general topology" question than an "algebraic topology" question. What is the context of the question? Are you expected to use tools from algebraic topology to show that the spaces are homeomorphic? Also, do you need only show that the spaces are homeomorphic, or do you need to explicitly exhibit a homeomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the function
\begin{align}
&\varphi:Y\to X&&(x,y)\mapsto\left(x+y,\frac{xy}{2\pi}+y\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Sir.... Will you please tell me the general mathod to find such mappings or at least any idea...  Thanks 